# Which field type is better to store specific play time in video for postgres?

Tags: postgresql, database-design

Friend and I are making video service.

In video table, we store opening start point and opening end point of each video. For example,

opening start time: 00:01:35

opening end time: 00:03:04

At first, I made each column with time(6) type. But my friend told me each column should be interval type.

So in following case, which is better?

1) Each column is time(6) type.

2) Each column is interval type.

3) opening start time column is time(6) type, and opening elasped time is interval type

Comment: Intervals can be added. But on the other hand, times can be subtracted from each other to get intervals. So there's no real advantage to either.

Comment: The answer totally depends on what you're going to do with these values.

Comment: Most probably `interval` or even `integer` (representing the total runtime in seconds). `time` is a **point** in time, not a duration - you wouldn't be able to store videos that run for longer than 24 hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Time is for representing time of day

Interval is for representing durations

Interval is probably the best fit for locating instants inside a video recording,  but an integer or bigint count of frame number is another candidate.